# Help manual of google checkout and paypal

Tags: paypal, checkout, manual

I'm trying to find help manuals of Google Checkout and PayPal with screenshots, online.

Answer (score -1):

The [Paypal Developer Network](https://www.x.com/index.jspa) contains documentation.

Google checkout really depends on how [you want to integrate](https://checkout.google.com/seller/developers.html?hl=en&gl=GB).

I don't know that either is going to really have a "help manual" for the entire service. Both Paypal and Google Checkout have a variety of services they provide, and the documentation you need will really depend on what you're trying to accomplish.